# From grep to perl: inverse matching by perl

Tags: perl, grep

it is pretty long time that I don't program in perl and I need some push.

I need to compare two lists in order to retain only the lines that are not matching.

my first file looks like this:

```
1   pf1 er2 0,4  
2   pf1 er3 0,56  
3   pf1 er6 0,72365  
4   er3 pf3 0,263
5   pf5 er2 0,28473
```

The second file is like:

```
pf1 er2
pf1 er3
er2 pf1
er3 pf1
```

And I would like to have an output like:

```
3   pf1 er6 0,72365  
4   er3 pf3 0,263
5   pf5 er2 0,28473
```

I used to do that by `grep -Fvf second_file.txt first-file.txt > output.txt`

Now i need to perform the same in perl, but I'm not able to organize a code.

```perl
open(HAN, "< $file_1") ||  die "Impossibile aprire il file $file_1";
@r = <HAN>;
close(HAN);
open(RES, "< $file_2") ||  die "Impossibile aprire il file $file_2";
@c = <RES>;
close(RES);

for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++){
    ($num, $id1, $id2, $v) = split (/\t/, $r[$i], 4);

    $ppi1 = $id1."\t".$id2;

    for($t=0; $t<=$#c; $t++){
        ($iid1, $iid2) = split (/ /, $c[$t]);
        $orto1 = $iid1."\t".$iid2;
        $orto2 = $iid2."\t".$iid1;

        if( ($ppi1 ne $orto1) || ($ppi1 ne $orto2) ){
            print "$ppi1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: What Perl code have you already written and how does it fail to do what the `grep` code does? See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the basics of how to run Perl. A good first step is likely to consider what the `grep` command does and the explain that in prose. Then, take that prose and rewrite it as a program.

Comment: @Corion I edited my question with the draft of the code I was writing

Comment: For that grep to work, second file can't be using `|`. Perhaps ` `?

Comment: Why is the `while` inside the `for`? And why does it try to read `<$RES>` when you already emptied it into `@c` (and closed it!) ?

Comment: @jhnc I edited the post

Comment: First thing I would do is to add `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Then fix the errors you'll get.

Comment: `for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++){` -> `for my $r (@r) {` and `$r[$i]` -> `$r`.

Comment: The logic of your perl (`$orto1`/`$orto2` assignments) indicates that you actually wanted to run grep without `-F` and with second file containing `|` delimiters. However in that case, you wouldn't get the output you show as lines 4 and 5 would also be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that sample data, you want to exclude lines from the first file if the second and third columns match the first and second columns of a line of the second file. Storing the second file's columns in a hash and then checking for existence of those keys when reading the first file is an easy, very time efficient approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my ($data_file, $excludes_file) = @ARGV;

my %excludes;
open my $ex, "<", $excludes_file;
while (<$ex>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split;
  $excludes{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} = 1;
}

open my $data, "<", $data_file;
while (<$data>) {
  my @F = split;
  print unless exists $excludes{$F[1]}->{$F[2]};
}
```

Running it will give:

```
$ perl filter.pl file1.txt file2.txt
3   pf1 er6 0,72365  
4   er3 pf3 0,263
5   pf5 er2 0,28473
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one not very elaborate, but working solution:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

#my @first_file_lines = split "\n", `cat ./first_file.txt`;
#my @second_file_lines = split "\n",`cat ./second_file.txt`;
open( my $fh, '<', './first_file.txt' );
open( my $fh1, '<', './second_file.txt' );
chomp ( my @first_file_lines = <$fh> );
chomp (my @second_file_lines = <$fh1>) ;

close( $fh );
close( $fh1 );


my @output = grep { filter( $_, \@second_file_lines ) } @first_file_lines;

sub filter {
    my $current    = shift;
    my $compare_to = shift;

    for my $comp ( @$compare_to ) {
        my $comp1 = $comp;
        $comp1 =~ s/\|/ /;
        if ( $current =~ /^$comp1/ ) {
            say 'equal: ' . "$current   :  $comp";
            return;
        }
    }


    return $current;
}

say Dumper( @first_file_lines );
say Dumper( @second_file_lines );

for my $out ( @output ) {
    `echo "$out" >> ./output.txt`;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm on a windows machine and I cannot use "cat".

Comment: I edited the code. You can use the Perl built-in open in order to read the files.
The same applies for writing into a file too. open ( my $fh, '>', './output.txt');

Comment: as output I get only the file 1 content

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

- read lines from the reference file

  - quote the contents of the line to make it compatible for compiling a regex from
- compile a combined regex which ORs all matches together

  - for your example that would be `(?:pf1 er2|pf1 er3|er2 pf1|er3 pf1)`
- read lines from STDIN

  - print the line to STDOUT unless the regex matches

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my($reference) = @ARGV;

my $fh;
open($fh, "<". $reference)
    or die "open '${reference}': $!\n";
my @matches;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push(@matches, quotemeta);
}
close($fh)
    or die "close '${reference}': $!\n";

# compile combined regex
my $regex = join('|', @matches);
$regex = qr/(?:${regex})/;

while (<STDIN>) {
    print unless $_ =~ $regex;
}

exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ cat dummy1.txt
1   pf1 er2 0,4  
2   pf1 er3 0,56  
3   pf1 er6 0,72365  
4   er3 pf3 0,263
5   pf5 er2 0,28473

$ cat dummy2.txt
pf1 er2
pf1 er3
er2 pf1
er3 pf1

$ perl dummy.pl <dummy1.txt dummy2.txt
3   pf1 er6 0,72365  
4   er3 pf3 0,263
5   pf5 er2 0,28473
```

Comment: @Gabelins updated my answer to be more efficient, i.e. only do one regex match.

Comment: Updated the answer to act as filter, i.e. the input to filter is passed in through STDIN (see command line example).